# Delete files with different names in Python

Tags: python, glob

I am trying to delete several files within a directory.

So far I have that code:

```
   for filename in glob.glob("buffer*" ):
        os.remove(filename) 
    for filename in glob.glob("grid*" ):
        os.remove(filename)
    for filename in glob.glob("OSMroads*" ):
        os.remove(filename)
    for filename in glob.glob("newCostSurface*" ):
        os.remove(filename)
    for filename in glob.glob("standsLine*" ):
        os.remove(filename)
    for filename in glob.glob("standsReprojected*" ):
        os.remove(filename)
```

Is there a way to do this more efficient?

Comment: What files are you trying to delete? Is that the easiest way to group them? What are their filenames? We need more information.

Comment: What do you mean by "more efficient"? More efficient for humans to read/update/maintain your code? More efficient for the computer to run? Or something different?

Comment: I mean both: More efficient to read and more efficient so my code executes faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing 6 separate `glob` calls will of course iterate the directory object 6 times.

Fortunately, on almost any platform, it'll probably end up being cached after the first time. Unless your directory is absolutely gigantic, this won't be a noticeable problem.

But since you explicitly asked about efficiency, you can obviously iterate once and filter the results. The easiest way to do this is with [`fnmatch`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html). All that [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#module-glob) is doing is calling `listdir` and then `fnmatch` on each result; you can do the same thing with multiple `fnmatch` calls:

```
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, 'buffer*'):
        os.remove(filename)
    # etc.
```

And of course you can simplify this in exactly the same way partofthething simplified your existing code:

```
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    for pattern in ['buffer*', 'grid*', 'OSMroads*',
                    'newCostSurface*','standsLine*', 'standsReprojected*']:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, pattern):
            os.remove(filename)
```

Or:

```
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    if any(fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, pattern)
           for pattern in ['buffer*', 'grid*', 'OSMroads*',
                           'newCostSurface*','standsLine*', 'standsReprojected*']):
        os.remove(filename)
```

If you really need to squeeze out another tiny fraction of a percent performance, you can use `fnmatch.translate` to convert each pattern to a regexp, then merge the regexps into an alternation, and compile it, and then apply that regexp object to each filename. But the CPU time for `fnmatch` compared to the I/O time for reading the directory objects is probably so small the improvement wouldn't even be measurable.

Comment: Very nice answer. I'm a lazy typist myself, I'd use `"buffer grid OSMroads etc".split()` instead of the list, and `pattern+'*'` when matching. Is it pythonic or just too lazy?

Comment: @ManuelGutierrez: Well, if that's too lazy, then I'd say you're in good company. Notice that stdlib types like [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) and [`enum`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/enum.html#functional-api) effectively have that `split()` built-in, because everyone in the `namedtuple` discussions (including most of the core devs) was writing `namedtuple('Point', 'x y z'.split())`, and someone suggested that was worth making even shorter.

Answer (score 6):

I like using lists so I don't repeat code, like this:

```
for pattern in ['buffer*','grid*','OSMroads*','newCostSurface*','standsLine*'
                'standsReprojected*']:
    for filename in glob.glob(pattern):
        os.remove(filename)
```